# subprocess.check_output appends \n even if string did not contain it

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess

Using Python, I am trying to run the following `git` command.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-parse", "--short=7", "HEAD"])
commit = output.decode("utf-8")
print("Repo is on commit ", commit)

# Works well until here but in the below line it fails to understand commit
version = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--tags', f'{commit}'])
```

**Question:**
It works well but for the last line. The second call to `subprocess.check_output` does not understand `commit` very well even though the variable `commit` has the correct value. It complains the following error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'describe', '--tags', '6959fdf\n']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

The `\n` exists in `commit` even if `commit` has printed correctly without the `\n` a few lines above.

Comment: What do you mean by "has printed correctly without the `\n`"? I think the output of `git rev-parse` just contains that newline.

Comment: Are you sure that the "print" didn't output an additional empty line (as `\n` is just the newline character)?

Comment: `git describe --tags 6959fdf` works well from command line. I just want to get it working through `subprocess` in my Python script

Answer (score 1):

`output` (from `subprocess.check_output(…)` has the newline. Strip it off:

```
commit = output.strip().decode("ascii")
```

Comment: Using ascii strips off the `\n` but I still get the error saying `fatal: Not a valid object name 6959fdf`

Comment: `git describe --tags 6959fdf` works well from command line. But `subprocess.check_output` complains about the last parameter not being a valid object.